# Placing image above an image in title page

Tags: graphics, titles, article

I want to add two filled rectangle()red,blue in title page. How i can place the red rectangle above the blue one. The red rectangle is smaller than blue.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly add a minimal working example so that we can understand what you need. Anyhow, as far I understood is, you have some title and you need to place some rectangle above (or below). Here is the simple solution using `tikz`.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[color = blue, fill]  (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[color = red, fill]  (0,2.1) rectangle (2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}   

    \huge \textbf{Do you want the title Here ?}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: @tovino HI tovino.. Welcome. Always add a minimal working example which explains your effort in doing the same(or atleast document class with `\begin{document} \end{document}`). Then you will get your answer immediately in this site, most of the time.

Comment: @tovino upvote if it solve your question. Thats the way to thank the people who answers your question.